# issue with reading multiple span tag using JAWS

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am trying simple HTML structure to read by JAWS screen reader

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test code</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <span tabindex="0">
        <span>first line</span>
        <span>second line</span>
    </span>
</body>
```

on tab out from A tag focus is get set on next focusable SPAN tag because of tabIndex. But JAWS in not able to read all content in that SPAN when its focused. It reads only first child SPAN content and skips second SPAN content.

I need help on code changes with which JAWS will read both SPAN tags on focus.

Answer (score 0):

Since JAWS only reads the first element, maybe you can try this:

```
    <style type="text/css">            
    .marked-hidden-for-reader{
       display:none;
    }
    </style>

    <span tabindex="0">
        <span class="marked-hidden-for-reader">first line second line</span>
        <span>first line</span>
        <span>second line</span>
    </span>
```